# Wrong answer on Codechef

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on the problem [link](https://www.codechef.com/problems/LUCKY5)

Code:

```
lenInput= int(input())
 while lenInput:
   temCnt=0
   proInput = str(input())
   lenCnt= len(proInput)
   for i in range (lenCnt):
     if (proInput[i] == '4') or (proInput[i] =='7'):
       temCnt+=1
   print(lenCnt -temCnt)
   lenInput-=1
```

I am able to get the correct output for the use cases mentioned in the site,but while submitting my code.
It's throw an error "Wrong answer"

Can you please help me in understand ,why the error is thrown ?

Comment: You could individually use `count()` to get the count of `'4'` and `'7'` and print the result of `len - sumOfCount(4, 7)`.

Comment: [This question is being discussed on meta.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367866/what-to-do-with-a-coding-challenge-question-where-the-problem-statement-is-in-an)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you `str(input())`? `input()` already gives you a string to begin with.

The only action needed here is changing any non-lucky digit into a lucky one. The amount of changes needed is the amount of non-lucky numbers:

```
for _ in range(int(input())):    # loop over each test case
    i = 0                          # start counting at 0
    for c in input():              # loop over each character of input testcase
        if c not in ['4','7']:     # if character not lucky, count it
            i+=1
    print(i)                     # print count
```

Comment: or indeed `print(sum(1 for c in input() if c not in {'4', '7'}))`

Comment: In Python2, input doesn't always return a str

Comment: @cricket_007 you do see the `python-3.x` tag on the question? for 2.x you should switch to `raw_input()` instead, but nothing in the questions suggests 2.x to me.

Comment: I'm just saying, for someone who may know Python2, then `str(input())` makes sense